# Collapsing toolbar not pin the card view

Tags: android, parallax, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have created a XML with appbar layout, collapsing toolbar layout with imageview and nested scroll view in order to preform parallax scrolling.

However, I want to add a cardview inside the collapsing toolbar and pin it using the collapsing mode. It can't pin after scroll up. I have no idea what I made wrong. Anyone can help?

Here is my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"


    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout

        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00FFFFFF">


        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingtoolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

                //textview
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView7"
                        android:layout_width="360dp"
                        android:layout_height="360dp"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo"
                        tools:srcCompat="@drawable/logo" />




    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="false"
        android:overScrollMode="always"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            //my content
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, only `Toolbar` can be pinned inside of `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. Everything else collapses. So you either put your layout you want to pin inside of Toolbar Layout (not recommended, will change size of toolbar, and positions of nav buttons, etc.) or you move it outside of CollapsingToolbar.

Just remember that `AppBarLayout` acts like a vertical LinearLayout.

One possible idea, if you design allows it, is to remove `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and try to build your UI inside of `AppBarLayout`. You can control what goes away and what stays using `layout_scrollFlags`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple technique that you can apply

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/home_bg_color"
        tools:context=".ui.match_detailds.MatchDetailsActivity">
        <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
            <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/app_barlayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
                <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                    android:id="@+id/collaps_toolabar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/CollapsingToolbarLayoutExpandedTextStyle"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">
                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_150sdp"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>
                    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_150sdp"

                        app:layout_collapseMode="pin">
                    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

                    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                        android:id="@+id/layout_currentMatch_item"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_150sdp"
                        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                        app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="1">

                    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

                </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
            </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

            <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                android:id="@+id/nestedviewhome"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
        </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```